# Would it be slower to place function definitions inside another function definition?

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

Will it be slower to place functions' defintions inside a main function? 
 I usually do that if the subfunctions are short. 
However, with a long subfunction I usually place it outside as I think that would make it easier to read and run faster.

Now I want to do it as the first method below as I want to make it self-contained and easier to manage when I do copy-paste and re-use. 
 If I place them outside, I usually miscopy some functions and make it not running properly. But I'm worrying if it's slower and harder to read.

I understand about the local/global effect but I want to focus on the speed and readability here.

**Method 1:**
Place `function1` and `function2` inside the main function.

```
   myFunction[parameters_] := Module[{},
  
  function1[parameters1_] := Module[{},
    (* a long function*)
    do something here
    ];
  function2[parameters2_] := Module[{},
    (* a short function*)
    do something here
    ];
  
  (*use function1 and function2 to do something more*)
  
  ]
```

**Method 2:**

```
  function1[parameters1_] := Module[{},
    (* a long function*)
    do something here
    ];

  function2[parameters2_] := Module[{},
    (* a short function*)
    do something here
    ];

myFunction[parameters_] := Module[{},
  
  (*use function1 and function2 to do something more*)
  
  ]
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark not much difference for my current case but I can imagine that I may put 10 functions' definitions inside a function and not quire sure what would it be.

Comment: Is there an intent of these functions to be visible outside `myFunction`, or to specifically not be visible? With the above construct they're definitely visible outside.

Comment: @kirma I don't have intention to use them outside. In the first method I place function1 and function2 inside another function  so I believe they're local only. Am I wrong?

Comment: @internet You should put their names in the list of symbols in the first argument of `Module` then. Anyway, their definitions will be re-evaluated every time you call the main function, which is not great. What you might want to do is to have a `Module` which contains both helper functions *and* the main function, and all functions which you want to stay invisible listed as `Module` symbols. This way their definitions would be evaluated only once and only main function would be visible.

Comment: @kirma you're right. I forgot about that. As for adding Module which contains both helper functions and the main function, could you add it as answer or any reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you told on the comments that you want the internal functions not to be visible probably the best method is the following:

Define all functions, internal and main, inside a `Module`. Put those functions which you don't want to be publicly visible on the `Module` symbols list; the rest will become publicly visible. There shouldn't be performance issues; all definitions are evaluated only once.

```
Module[
 {function1, function2},

 function1[parameters1_] := 
  (Echo["function1 was here"]; parameters1);

 function2[parameters2_] := 
  (Echo["function2 was here"]; parameters2);

 myFunction[parameters_] :=
  (function1[parameters]; 
   function2[parameters]);
 ]
```

Now the main function is visible and can call internal functions:

```
myFunction[42]

(* function1 was here *)

(* function2 was here *)

(* 42 *)
```

At the same time, internal functions are not publicly visible:

```
function1[42]

(* function1[42] *)

function2[42]

(* function2[42] *)
```

Comment: I see. I think this is what I'm looking for. If I copy it somewhere then I just need to copy the whole module.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a big difference, but for housekeeping the first method is to be preferred:

```
myFunction[] := Module[{},
   function1[] := Module[{},
     Sqrt /@ Range[10^4]];
   function2[] := Module[{},
     Sqrt /@ Range[10^4];];
   function1[];
   function2[]];
myFunction[] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.135302, Null} *)


function1[] := Module[{}, Sqrt /@ Range[10^4];];
function2[] := Module[{}, Sqrt /@ Range[10^4];];
myFunction[] := Module[{}, function1[]; function2[]]
myFunction[] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.114168, Null} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you usually write it as the first method?

Comment: If function1 is only used inside another one and it is simple and not hard to debug, I usually include it in the outer function.